# How to create a dynamic bar-chart in android using achartengine?

Tags: android, charts

Can any one tell me how to create a dynamic bar-chart in android using achartengine.I have did some searches on Google but they are all not making me clear.
If possible can any one please convey me one sample program code to create a dynamic bar-chart in android using achartengine.

Thanks for your precious time!..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach is quite simple: you just need to update your dataset and then call the `repaint()` method on your `mChartView`. The graph display will be updated with the new data.

Please see [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E9fozQ5NlSo) video presentation on how exactly to do that.